# In how many ways could $15$ people be divided into groups?

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways could $15$ people be divided into

1. five groups containing, respectively, one, two, three, four, and five people?
2. three groups (not distinct) of five people?

For the first one I got

$$C(15,1) C (14,2) C(12,3) C9,4) C (5,5)= \frac{15! 14! 12! 9! 5!}{14! 1! 12! 2! 9! 3! 5! 4! 5! 0!}= \frac{15!}{1! 2! 3! 4! 5!}=37,837,800 $$
Is this correct?

Comment: In general, people here will not solve your homework for you.  Instead, you should include your thoughts and what you tried and people will help you come up with ideas or the next step.

Comment: For the first one i got, i wanna see if im corrct... C (15,1)* C (14,2)* C(12,3)* C9,4)* C (5,5)= (15!*14!*12!*9!*5!)/(14!*1!*12!*2!*9!*3!*5!*4!*5!*0)= (15!)/(1!*2!*3!*4!*5!)=37,837,800

Answer (score 1):

the general formula for second question is $\frac{3m!}{3!.(m!)^3}$ so here $m=5$ so answer to your second question is $\frac{15!}{3!.(5!)^3}$. for first question look up on your own on the net for permutations and combinations of dissimilar things divided into $a,b,c..$ groups . Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks!! I was stuck for a moment!

Comment: @ IH.M33 Your welcome.